# Masking several APIs behind a common API for an end user

Tags: rest, session-state, api-design

**Note**: I would like to start by stating that the nature of this query is quite general as I am exploring ways to implement something as opposed to trying to solve a specific coding issue or problem

I am working on a middleware project that sits between a set of producers (of information) and a single consumer.

*Below are the requirements*.

1) The producers all generate data for the consumer but have their own API interfaces.

2) The consumer doesnt really want to code to every producer's API and hence has requested that a transparency layer be created that abstracts all the producers and provides it with just one API interface to code to.

3) More producers will be added from time to time.

4) The information that each producer sends will, by nature, be of a similar type (e.g. stock holdings - which contain a defined set of common attributes). However the representation within each producer's API is to their own discretion.

5) There must be secure communication between the consumer and each producer where the producer verifies the consumer before providing the data.

I am sure you might have questions around these requirements or require more clarifications, so please let me know and I will update the question.

However, ***here are my questions*** and was hoping some of the experts on here can provide some advice and guidance.

A) I was inclined towards using a RESTful API for the consumer with JSON responses using a JAVA component in the backend to do the translations. This would make it scalable to add more producers (and all their quirks and discretionary representations could be abstracted from the consumer). Do you think its a good idea or would you suggest an alternative approach?

B) There is an element of authentication and non-repudiation here. Each producer might have their own way of implementing this - either via digital signatures, tokens and access codes, one time passwords sent to the consumer to provide back as a 2-factor authentication, etc etc. Any tips on how this could be implemented and standardized? What technologies should I consider?

C) Since authentication sessions need to be maintained, is this against RESTful principles?

Any help or feedback you can provide is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i'll try to give you my vision of how I would solve this problem.

1. **Start from the consumer** - you say that you will have only a consumer so you can easly understand what kind of API interaction the cunsumer is expecting. Then you can design a draft of the API that your middleware must expose. This will help you when will have to design and develop the middleware features.
2. **Collect all the authentication requirements** - produce a list of all the types of authentication that the "producers" requuire and keep in mind that each consumer "user" must provide all the informations needed for all the authenication types.
3. **Auth MIddleware** - with the information got from the point 2, design an authentication middleware that can manage all the authentication methodologies required by your producers. This means to think about a way to manage all the producers credentials. **This compoment only interact with the Logic Middleware**
4. **Logic Middleware** -  as the name suggests, manages all the component interactions

   a. provides **simple authentication** towards the consumer, for example a simple api token

   b. uses a proprietary **domain model**, this frees you from the specific domain of your producers although you say that they are consistent and helps you to design integration functions with more freedom and decoupling from all the actors involved

   c. uses the **Auth Middleware** starting from the api token provided by the consumer in order to authenticate towards each producer involved into the specific orchestration

Hope this could help you!